# Atom, how to position opening file in last tab?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm using Atom editor and when I open an existing file or create a new one Atom positions the file directly after the current tab.

What I want is to position every opened or created file in last in my tabs list.

For example, in the following picture, when I'm working of `File1.py` I want every opened of new file to be positioned after `File3.py` in my tabs.

[image]

Someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for this as this is annoying especially when you have multiple tabs already open. I almost gave up as there is no discussion on this, but while looking through the settings found this simple setting.

Settings > Packages > Tabs > Add New Tabs At End: Check

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7tSn.png)